# Can't copy files into directory which has enough group permissions

Tags: permissions, cp

I would like to do this:

```
XXXX:xxxadm 53> cp /user/uz408217/transporty/K900730.ZAT /usr/sap/trans/cofiles
```

But end up with this error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/sap/trans/cofiles/K900730.ZAT': Permission denied
```

Here are the permissions of concerned directories:

```
drwxrwx--x  2 root   sapsys      69632 Jun 25 13:35 cofiles
drwxrwx--x  2 root   sapsys      61440 Jun 25 13:35 data
```

Here you can see my user is, indeed, in group sapsys:

```
XXX:ap1adm 58> groups
sapsys sapinst dba oper oinstall asmdba asmoper
```

Any idea why I can't copy it there?

I've checked parent directories and they should be ok.
.. :

```
drwxrwxrwx 20  17370 sapsys     4096 Jun 28 12:15 trans
```

../.. :

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 smdadm sapsys  4096 Aug  5  2017 sap
```

../../.. :

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   root      4096 Apr 15  2014 usr
```

"/usr" is not owned by any of group ap1adm is member of, but it has execute but for other, so that should not be a problem, right?

PS: Can, let's say, root override "default" working of permissions? I'm not sure wether I phrased this PS in a way that's clear what I want to know...

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Please add result of `ls -l /usr/sap/trans/cofiles/K900730.ZAT`

Comment: Do you have `x` permissions on the intermediate directories in the path `/usr/sap/trans/cofiles`?

Answer (score -1):

you are executing command `cp` by user `ap1adm`. as I see directory `cofiles` doesn't have permission on others. `sapsys` group has full permission on directory `cofiles`. To assign these group permissions to user `ap1adm` , user should be  in group as he is and *user should be owner of the group `sapsys`. so make `ap1adm` group owner of directory `sapsys`. You can use following commands:

```
chgrp  ap1adm  /usr/sap/trans/cofiles
```

or

```
chown  :ap1adm  /usr/sap/trans/cofiles
```

Comment: User `ap1adm` is already a member of group `sapsys`, so group permissions apply to the situation.